# Does Entity Framework 4.0 allow to work without designers?

Tags: entity-framework, efv4

I currently enjoy working with NHibernate + Fluent NHibernate. I considered Entity Framework v1 because of its mature Linq support but I do not like working with clicky designers; and it did not support POCO, anyway. Now EF v4 does support POCOs; however, does it still require to use designers? Well, maybe I can edit those XML files but it cannot be considered a programming activity (unless you're doing J2EE I think).

So, would I be able to use Entity Framework only from the C# code, including model definition, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,

There is an add-on to .NET 4.0 that allows you to do this without a designer, it is called Code-Only you can find it here: In the [CTP for Beta 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2009/11/04/ado-net-entity-framework-community-technology-preview-released.aspx)

The current version works against EF / .NET 4.0 Beta 2.

Check out [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/efdesign/archive/2009/10/12/code-only-further-enhancements.aspx) on the EF design blog more on how to use Code-Only.
Also check on [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/10/14/code-only-best-practices.aspx) on my blog.

Hope this Helps.

Alex

Comment: Thanks, this is more than enough to start digging myself.